# recursion is not happening for the remaining cases

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int a[102][102]={0};int b[100]={0};int ans=0;
int find(int i,int j,int n)
{
    if(j>n)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(a[i][j]==1)
    {
        cout<<j<<endl;
        int s=find(j,0,n);
        if((s+1)%2==0&&s!=0)
        {
            ans++;
        }
        return s+1;
    }
    int s=find(i,j+1,n);
}

int main() {

    int i,j,n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        a[y][x]=1;
    }

        int s=find(1,0,n);
        cout<<ans<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying a problem on graphs and got stuck with it. The recursion is not happening for the remaining values of j, where a[i][j]=1. it happens always for the first case only. Can any of you guys help me out with this?

Comment: Your `find` function has undefined behavior when `j <= n`, and `a[i][j]!=1`, due to missing `return` statement.

Comment: You have the `return` statement inside the `if`. It will cause all recursions to return. You need to get rid of it. It looks like you might need to have a `list` of answers in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've solved it. As you have said , I've made some changes to the find function and did it. :)